# Difference between AOMDV and AODV tcl script

Tags: ns2

Is there any other changes to the tcl file of AOMDV.tcl(the one that is given in ex/tcl) other than changing the routing protocol to AODV to create a AODV tcl script?

Answer (score 0):

---

Changing set `val(rp) AOMDV` to `set val(rp) AODV` :

"aomdv.tcl" works OK. `$ ns aomdv.tcl` : The files ns.trc 182.2MB, scenario.trc 1.5kB are created.

More aodv examples : **aodv-examples-05.2014.tar.gz** (Not all the files are the AODV protocol.)

Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTGQ1QWtPenN4Mm8/view?usp=sharing

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2) [aodv](/questions/tagged/aodv)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i tried that and the results where totally different from theory.(AODV is showing better performance in terms of Packet Delivery Ratio)